# Adding a folder in Windows 10 Explorer to the Quick-access/favorites to access it with only one click

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, favorites

Currently when I'm adding a folder to the favorites I have to click twice for accessing the folder.
Click on "Favorites" in the tree pane and then on the folder in the main pain to open it.

The Favorites are not expanded. Therefore two clicks are needed:
1: Click to navigate to favorite
2: Click on the actual favorite folder I want to navigate to

The Quick Access folder seems to be disabled completely (I can not drop folders there).
Right click on the favorites shows a Expand option but it is disabled (greyed out)
(What is the difference between them)

How to expand the favorites to make the folder I want navigate to accessible with one click. Or the Quick Access.

In the past (Windows 7, ...) the favorite folder was directly accessible in the tree pane. 
Is this somehow still possible?

Comment: Do you mean you have to click to expand the Favorites tree? If you don't mean that, please explain what you mean by "click twice"?

Comment: @music2myear: I don't have the favorites expanded. So I have to click to navigate to the favorites folder (click one) and than on the actual favorite (click two). Right click on the favorites shows a Expand option but it is disabled (greyed out)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Folder Options`→`Click items as follows` and select the `Single-click to open an item (point to select)` radio button：

[image]

Comment: I think that is a misunderstanding of the click twice.